# How should we create / adjust tags to account for Godot versioning?

Tags: discussion, tags

Godot 4.x has [numerous differences](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) from 3.x, so it seems logical that it should have its own tag. But that would leave us with `Godot` & `Godot4`, which seems a bit confusing.

Potentially complicating things, both 3.x & 4.x have standard versions & versions with .Net/C# support. I'd favor using separate tags to indicate C# use rather than add something like `Godot4C#` as its own tag, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: AFAIK, we typically create version specific tags when there are significant differences in architecture and API that would make answers specific to a version irrelevant for another version.

Answer (score 2):

I propose the following:

**Keep the unversioned [godot](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godot) tag**

This tag would act as a default landing point for less experienced users that aren't familiar with the version differences. It also would serve general Godot questions that aren't affected by or concerned with version differences.

**Add versioned tags for both [godot3](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godot3) & [godot4](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godot4)**

These allow users that are familiar with &/or affected by version differences to signal their needs up front.

**Retag [godot](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godot) with versioned tags where applicable**

As indicated in the comments, there's about 200 total Godot questions. Filtering with search we have:

- Only four of them [include 4 in the title](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgodot%5D+title%3A4).
- About 50 [include 4 anywhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgodot%5D+4).
- Six with [3 in the title](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgodot%5D+title%3A3).
- 60-70 with [3 anywhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgodot%5D+3).

I'd say we retag the ones with versions mentioned in the title first. If folks want look through the others, that's great, but if not, we can leave them to be organically retagged over time as needed.

**Update the tag guidance to reflect the above changes**

Generally a good idea, though I question how often it gets read.

I patterned this solution based on how we handled [directx](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directx) & the related version tags.

One problem with this solution is that there may be times where a question gets tags with version X, but the situation isn't really version specific. I'm not sure if we should advise domain experts to notice this and retag with [godot](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/godot) instead or if it's fine to leave it up to the reader to determine which posts to read through.

Also, I'm not sure if versions 1 & 2 need tags of their own or not. Currently we have:

- Zero questions [created between 2012 to Feb 2016](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgodot%5D+created%3A2014..2016-01) which covers the time between Godot 1 & 2 being released. This is just the "certainly version 1" range as it's possible that Godot 1 questions could have been asked after 2015.
- 37 questions [created between Feb 2016 to 2017](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgodot%5D+created%3A2016-02..2017) which covers the time between Godot 2 & 3 being released; this is the "certainly < version 3" range.

I based the above off the data in the
[Godot release policy page](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/about/release_policy.html).

Comment: I wasn't able to find a way to capture a URL that showed a search through the tags for all the various directx versioned tags. If someone figures that out, please toss in an edit!

Comment: I like this except for the "keep the unversioned `godot` tag". I think that's a recipe for ambiguity when a new user tags their question `godot`, asks "how do I do X?" and the first comment inevitably has to be "...are you using Godot 4?" because the answer is different in each version. I think forcing a new user to make a choice when tagging is helpful and a not-unreasonable amount of friction. Do we have questions that are specific to Godot 1/2 that need coverage?

Comment: That's a good question -  I'm not familiar with versions 1 or 2, but I can update my answer to at least acknowledge them & if I find something substantial, I'll update to include relevant info.

Comment: I'm a newcomer to this specific stack exchange, learning Godot. Was trying to tag my questions with both `godot` and `godot-4` when it was specific to v4 being different from v3 (but wasn't allowed to do so because I haven't enough reputation to create tags from a question). - Either way, as someone learning Godot I find that 95% of all stuff is _not_ version-specific and having all three options is useful.